# Deleting Expired ASP.net Session State Data with AWS Dynamodb provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-dynamodb

I have create a new ASP.NET MVC 5 Project. I have installed through Nuget the AWS SDK for .NET and Session Provider and I have read [this article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-dynamodb-session.html) in Amazon: Article

I have this configuration in the Web.Config

```html
 <sessionState
  mode="Custom"
  customProvider="DynamoDBSessionStoreProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DynamoDBSessionStoreProvider"
      type="Amazon.SessionProvider.DynamoDBSessionStateStore, AWS.SessionProvider"
      AWSProfileName="default"
      Table="ASP.NET_SessionState"
      Region="eu-west-1"
      />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

I am looking for some resources for Deleting Expired Session-Store Data
similar to

DeleteExpiredSessions.sql
and 
ExpireUnusedSessions.sql

to manage expired data in AWS DynamoDb

Comment: Can you at least give a reason for down vote . I have just started with aws and trying to migrate asp.net session state form sql to dynamo. what is the best way to get rid of unsed session and delete expired session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK provides a method called `DeleteExpiredSessions`
described as:

> A utility method for cleaning up expired sessions that IIS failed to
>   delete. The method performs a scan on the ASP.NET_SessionState table
>   with a condition that the expiration date is in the past and calls
>   delete on all the keys returned. Scans can be costly on performance so
>   use this method sparingly like a nightly or weekly clean job.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_SessionProvider_DynamoDBSessionStateStore.htm

I've not used it, but it sounds like it's up to you to schedule a job that calls this method rather than run a SQL statement in the SQL job scheduler as in the MS SQL world. So write a c# program that calls it and schedule it in Windows scheduler? or use one of the IIS events to call it asynchronously from your web app? (asynchronous, otherwise you could end up blocking Application_Start for a long time if you were using that event for example)